# How do I display a tree of things in Bash?

Tags: bash, ubuntu-9.10

How do I make a tree of all things with bash? What is the command?

Comment: All things? It can be really hard. `tree` can be used for file system and `pstree` for processes. Possibly there are other `*tree` tools. Google can be invaluable here.

Answer (score 12):

```
tree /
```

or

```
find /
```

Update: @OP, since you have so much trouble with it, how about this alternative. On ubuntu 9.10, you should have bash 4.0 ? so try this

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
for rdir in /*/
do
    for file in $rdir/**
    do
      echo "$file"
    done
done
```

Comment: none of them work...i'm using virtual machine, could be that?

tree / says that is not installed

Comment: If tree isn't installed on your Ubuntu machine use: `sudo aptitude install tree`

Comment: the same...0 packages installed :S

Comment: findutils is a dependency of libc6, which many, many core packages (including apt!) depend on.  And Ben gave correct instructions for installing `tree`.  So I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: The tree package (http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/tree) is part of the universe packages, which might not be enabled. I would ask this question on the Ubuntu forums as it's not strictly programming related and they would likely already have resources to point you towards to help you out.

Answer (score 8):

you should probably alias this :)

`ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'`

(Warning: huge output)

Comment: How do I make this traverse all the way down?

Answer (score 5):

`tree -R /`

and then cry because it's enormous.

On a related note, to stop the command, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Comment: says that tree is not installed

Comment: Like I commented to ghostdog74's answer, install it with this command: `sudo aptitude install tree`

Comment: i already try to install...after i write tree and says is not installed

Comment: @pedro You need to `hash -r` or open a different terminal in order to refresh which executables are on the path.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ find . -print | sed -e 's;/*/;|;g;s;|; |;g'
```

Add alias to ~/.bash_profile

```
alias tree="find . -print | sed -e 's;/*/;|;g;s;|; |;g'"
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to find something from tree, do

```
    tree / > tree.txt
```

Then Ctrl + F it.